# how to switch spring boot startup class based on active spring profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I think i misunderstood Spring boot profiles functionality. 
I have two separate startup classes (ApplicationLocal and ApplicationProduction) in my spring boot application, 
These classes are annotated like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(value={Config.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.abc.*"})
@Profile("local")
public class ApplicationLocal extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
//

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(value={Config.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.abc.*"})
@Profile("production")
public class ApplicationProduction extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
//
```

and I want the appropriate startup class to get picked up by Spring boot at runtime depending on the value of -Dspring.profiles.active  jvm arguement. 
But its not working for me unless i mention start-class in  section in pom.xml
like this..

```
<properties>
    <start-class>com.abc.web.service.ApplicationLocal</start-class>
</properties>
```

If I don't mention the start-class in pom.xml then I get the following error: 
( i run the app as following

```
mvn spring-boot:run  -Drun.jvmArguments=" -Dspring.profiles.active=local"
```

And I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project payee-list-ws: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE:run failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.abc.web.service.ApplicationProduction, com.abc.web.service.ApplicationLocal] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Is there really a need to have different classes? Is there so much different business logic of each profile? Or is there just some configuration differents like different database connections or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one main class and two configurations for each env:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(value={Config.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.abc.*"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
//

@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class ConfigProduction {
    //...
}

@Configuration
@Profile("Local")
public class ConfigLocal {
    //...
}
```

As main class will scan for beans, Spring will pick correct configuration based on your actual profile.